# iPhone's Mobile Safari: Special Characters

Tags: iphone, safari

The iPhone app I'm working on uses html help files and special characters such as

```
  ü  and ê
```

are being mangled my iPhone's mobile Safari.  Anything I can do to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using XHTML, ensure that the content of your files really is the encoding specified in the doctype. If you're using just plain HTML, consider using XHTML instead, or

- Use HTML entities (e.g. `&eacute;`)
- [Use the META tag to specify an encoding](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [numerical character references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML#Numeric_character_references)?  Alternatively, perhaps you can use a `<meta http-equiv="content-type" ...` element.  Also, maybe there's a better way to tell mobile Safari the character encoding of HTML files (equivalent to the server's HTTP Content-Type header)